# Pass variable to session using CherryPy

Tags: python, cherrypy

I have started using CherryPy on a project. I love it because of it's simplicity but the learning curve has been steep because of the lack of documentation.

First, I would like ot "set" a variable on the user's session.

```
@cherrypy.expose
def setter(self):
    email = "email@email.com"
    cherrypy.session["email"] = email
    return "Variable passed to session"
```

Second, I would like to call that variable from the session on a different function.

```
@cherrypy.expose
def getter(self):
    return cherrypy.session.get("email")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "set" example is correct.

```
cherrypy.session["email"] = email
```

But your "get" example should just be:

```
return cherrypy.session["email"]
```

Comment: It works! But, do you know why I can't store charrypy.session["email"] in a variable and then return the variable? (I get 500 Intenal Error: KeyError: 'variable_name')

Comment: Where are you declaring the variable? If you are trying to return it from a different function than it was declared/assigned then it will not be in scope. You also need to consider sequence, if you try to read the key "email" from the session before you have assigned it then you will get a key error.

Answer (score 1):

Are you enabling the sessions?

If you are using a config file then add:

```
[/]
tools.sessions.on = True
```

Or if you are passing a config dictionary to quickstart or something similar:

```
{'/': {'tools.session.on': True}}
```

Take a look into the docstring of the sessions module in https://github.com/cherrypy/cherrypy/blob/master/cherrypy/lib/sessions.py

Comment: Yes, 100% sure.